# Time estimation via an integral

Tags: integration, geometry

Can anyone please interpret how is this equation derived?

> We can estimate the *mean time of stay* of a mobile user in a circular coverage area of a base station as follows:
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}[\text{time of stay}] = \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{2R\cos(\theta)}{\text{user velocity}} \;\mathrm{d}\theta
> $$
>   where $R$ is the radius of the circular base station, and $\theta$ is the angle between the mobile user location and the center of the base station (circle center).

Why are the integration limits $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ used, and why is the integral divided by $\pi$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More context would have been great, but here is my guess.
Assume the user move in a straight, horizontal line.
The user will enter the base station coverage at some point $P$ on the circle circumference and exit at some point $Q$.
Let $\theta$ be the (oriented) angle between $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and the radius line segment between $P$ and the center of the station. In that configuration, the time the user spend in the station coverage area is precisely $\frac{2R\cos\theta}{\text{user velocity}}$.
With this parameterization, the valid values of $\theta$ are exactly between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Also this is an expected value, so you can't just compute the integral, you need to normalize. That's where the division by $\pi$ comes from.
In more detail, assuming you have uniform distribution on $\theta$, the probability density function is constant equal to $1/\pi$.
To compute the expected value of a function $f$, you would by definition compute
$$
\mathbb E[f]=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\text{pdf}(\theta)f(\theta)\,d\theta
=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{f(\theta)}\pi\,d\theta
$$